# Using different datastores in the Rails same app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nosql, rdbms, redis, key-value-store

So this is more or less an implementation question, this is the senario I have, basically we have an app which uses MySQL as it's datastore, user accounts, transactions etc, but we want to add in a robust charting feature and the data will be stored in Redis, now basically my question is:

Is it possible, and what are the best practices for integrating another datastore into an app which already depends on another one. Can I use Rack to generate the reports? etc...

I want to turn this into a sort of open discussion because I think the need for a solution like this is going to rise as we see more and more key/value stores that offer benefits far different than a RDBMS, an NoSQL stores as well. They all have their benefits but no one solution covers them all.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have models that do not inherit `ActiveRecord::Base`. Add your preferred Redis client gem, do whatever config is necessary, and start writing Redis models.

Comment: Are there any shortcomings to doing this? I'm just trying to figure out what the best method of handling my current situation is, thanks for the input thought!

Answer (score 0):

I can try to reopen this topic, because should be very practical.

Have same issue with this. I want to replicate data from SQL to NoSQL. SQL used as main database storage, because data integrity, relations etc. And NoSQL as secondary database storage set for reading. In SQL you have much associations divided to much tables. Many one-to-one association saved in different tables for better readability. This associations should be saved as one document with NoSQL. It gives unbelievable speed. Only one load. Great for data exchange for API.

Do someone positive experience with replication SQL data to more consistent NoSQL documents?